# Allow custom role (manager) to delete user

Tags: users

I'm required to allow custom roles (Manager and Editors) to **DELETE authenticated** user. 
I have tried [Administer Users by Role](https://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole), but the Managers and Editors will be able to access the user setting (MYSITE.COM/admin/config/people/accounts/settings), and this is a big security penalty.

Do you guys know an other way to do this without security issues? I'm using also [Role Delegation](https://drupal.org/project/role_delegation), but with it i'm just able to modify the roles per users

Thank you

Comment: just a quick idea, but perhaps you could use your existing setup, and use page manager to restrict access to the accounts/settings page with a role based context ?

Comment: Hum, I can't get there, sorry. How can I restrict the access for that page? Where can I locate the "page manager". Thank you

Comment: Assuming you have chaos tools installed, the page manager can be found under admin/structure/pages . Find the node/edit page in page manager and enable it. click edit, add a variant with a selection criterion of "User: role", select the roles you want to have access, click "reverse" at the bottom, choose a redirect for where you want the page to go when they don't have the right to edit. You can add a "Node: type" selection criterion also, to make it more specific

Comment: Yes, I have it (I'm using the Drupal Spark Profile). Actually I had no idea of the possibilities provided by the page manager. I'm following this tutorial ( http://vimeo.com/22193918 ), to get more information about it. I'll be back soon to provide news. Thank you